# How to call wpf function via JS when visiting https link

Tags: wpf

I need to execute a function defined in wpf project, which is called from JS in a `https` web page.
The demo project of all codes is here: https://github.com/tomxue/WebViewIssueInWpf

**JS part:**
The web page link is https://cmsdev.lenovo.com.cn/musichtml/leHome/weather/index.html?date=&city=&mark=0&speakerId=&reply=

And it contains below line:

```
<script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

And js/index.js contains below code:

```
setTitle(dataObject.city + weekDay(dataObject.date) +"天气" )
```

`setTitle()` is defined below: uses method of `window.external.notify()`

```
    function setTitle(_str){
        try{
            wtjs.setTitle(_str)
        }catch(e){
            console.log(_str)
            window.external.notify(_str);
        }
    }
```

The function `window.external.notify()` will call wpf function via `ScriptNotify()`.

**WPF part:**
For the WebView inside of the wpf project

```
        this.wv.IsScriptNotifyAllowed = true;
        this.wv.ScriptNotify += Wv_ScriptNotify;
```

And

```
    private void Wv_ScriptNotify(object sender, Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.WebViewControlScriptNotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock.Text = e.Value;
    }
```

**Problems:**

**(1)**
The problem here is if the web page uses `https://`, then the above function `Wv_ScriptNotify()` in wpf will not be fired. But if the web page link uses `http://`, then the above function `Wv_ScriptNotify()` in wpf can be fired.
Why and how to solve it?

**Update:** 
2020-3-2 17:25:55, tested just now, https works. I do not know what causes https does not work previously

**(2)**
JS in the web page uses a object wtjs (defined by ourselves and work well with an UWP project using JSBridge).
And I want to use a similiar method to UWP, using a bridge so that I can add multiple funtions/interfaces for JS to call. The disadvantage of ScriptNotify() is that only one interface is usable.
To achieve it, I make below code, which is commented out now.

```
wv.RegisterName("wtjs", new myBridge());
```

And more functions are defined as below

```
    public class myBridge
    {
        public void SetTitle(string title)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SetTitle is executing...title = {0}", title);
        }

        public void PlayTTS(string tts)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("PlayTTS is executing...tts = {0}", tts);
        }
    }
```

While in JS side, corresponding functions will be called.

```
wtjs.playTTS(tts)
wtjs.setTitle(_str)
```

But in fact wpf side did not work, while the UWP project using JSBridge works with the web link(so web page and JS script are workable). How to achieve it?

**(3)**

The above two problems are solved by DK Dhilip's answer already.
But a new problem is found. Please check my GitHub code, update it to latest commit.
https://github.com/tomxue/WebViewIssueInWpf

I put a TextBlock onto WebView and expect to see the text floating on the web content. But in fact, the text is covered by the WebView. Why and how to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Problem (1, 2)

HTTPS link worked fine for me, maybe the page is too slow to load?

According to Microsoft ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview#can-i-inject-native-objects-into-my-webviewcontrol-content)), only `ScriptNotify` is supported in `WebView`:

> **Can I inject native objects into my WebViewControl content?**
>
> No.
>   Neither the WebBrower (Internet Explorer) [ObjectForScripting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) property
>   nor the WebView (UWP) [AddWebAllowedObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.addweballowedobject) method are supported in
>   WebViewControl. As a workaround, you can use window.external.notify/
>   ScriptNotify and JavaScript execution to communicate between the
>   layers, for example:
>   https://github.com/rjmurillo/WebView_AddAllowedWebObjectWorkaround

But the above suggested workaround solution seems to work differently to your expectation, so I just implement my own solution to emulate the JSBridge convention you have expected.

My custom solution is not battle-tested, it might break in some edge cases but it seems to work fine in few simple tests.

**What's supported:**

- Multiple bridge objects
- JS to C# method call
- JS to C# get/set property

**C# Usage:**

```
// Add
webView.AddWebAllowedObject("wtjs", new MyBridge(this));
webView.AddWebAllowedObject("myBridge", new MyOtherBridge());

// Remove
webView.RemoveWebAllowedObject("wtjs");
```

**JS Usage:**

```
// Call C# object method (no return value)
wtjs.hello('hello', 'world', 666);
myBridge.saySomething('天猫精灵，叫爸爸！');

// Call C# object method (return value)
wtjs.add(10, 20).then(function (result) { console.log(result); });

// Get C# object property
wtjs.backgroundColor.then(function (color) { console.log(color); });

// Set C# object property
wtjs.niubility = true;
```

---

### Code

**WebViewExtensions.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    // Source: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/1269#issuecomment-171233788
    public static class JsonHelper
    {
        private static readonly Type[] _specialNumericTypes = { typeof(ulong), typeof(uint), typeof(ushort), typeof(sbyte) };

        public static object ConvertWeaklyTypedValue(object value, Type targetType)
        {
            if (targetType == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(targetType));

            if (value == null)
                return null;

            if (targetType.IsInstanceOfType(value))
                return value;

            var paramType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType) ?? targetType;

            if (paramType.IsEnum)
            {
                if (value is string)
                    return Enum.Parse(paramType, (string)value);
                else
                    return Enum.ToObject(paramType, value);
            }

            if (paramType == typeof(Guid))
            {
                return Guid.Parse((string)value);
            }

            if (_specialNumericTypes.Contains(paramType))
            {
                if (value is BigInteger)
                    return (ulong)(BigInteger)value;
                else
                    return Convert.ChangeType(value, paramType);
            }

            if (value is long || value is double)
            {
                return Convert.ChangeType(value, paramType);
            }

            return value;
        }
    }

    public enum WebViewInteropType
    {
        Notify = 0,
        InvokeMethod = 1,
        InvokeMethodWithReturn = 2,
        GetProperty = 3,
        SetProperty = 4
    }

    public class WebAllowedObject
    {
        public WebAllowedObject(WebView webview, string name)
        {
            WebView = webview;
            Name = name;
        }

        public WebView WebView { get; private set; }

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public ConcurrentDictionary<(string, WebViewInteropType), object> FeaturesMap { get; } = new ConcurrentDictionary<(string, WebViewInteropType), object>();

        public EventHandler<WebViewControlNavigationCompletedEventArgs> NavigationCompletedHandler { get; set; }

        public EventHandler<WebViewControlScriptNotifyEventArgs> ScriptNotifyHandler { get; set; }
    }

    public static class WebViewExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsNotification(this WebViewControlScriptNotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(e.Value);

                if (message["___magic___"] != null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            return true;
        }

        public static void AddWebAllowedObject(this WebView webview, string name, object targetObject)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

            if (targetObject == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(targetObject));

            if (webview.Tag == null)
            {
                webview.Tag = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebAllowedObject>();
            }
            else if (!(webview.Tag is ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebAllowedObject>))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("WebView.Tag property is already being used for other purpose.");
            }

            var webAllowedObjectsMap = webview.Tag as ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebAllowedObject>;

            var webAllowedObject = new WebAllowedObject(webview, name);

            if (webAllowedObjectsMap.TryAdd(name, webAllowedObject))
            {
                var objectType = targetObject.GetType();
                var methods = objectType.GetMethods();
                var properties = objectType.GetProperties();

                var jsStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                jsStringBuilder.Append("(function () {");
                jsStringBuilder.Append("window['");
                jsStringBuilder.Append(name);
                jsStringBuilder.Append("'] = {");

                jsStringBuilder.Append("__callback: {},");
                jsStringBuilder.Append("__newUuid: function () { return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, function (c) { return (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16); }); },");

                foreach (var method in methods)
                {
                    if (!method.IsSpecialName)
                    {
                        if (method.ReturnType == typeof(void))
                        {
                            webAllowedObject.FeaturesMap.TryAdd((method.Name, WebViewInteropType.InvokeMethod), method);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            webAllowedObject.FeaturesMap.TryAdd((method.Name, WebViewInteropType.InvokeMethodWithReturn), method);
                        }

                        var parameters = method.GetParameters();
                        var parametersInString = string.Join(",", parameters.Select(x => x.Position).Select(x => "$$" + x.ToString()));

                        jsStringBuilder.Append(method.Name);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(": function (");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(parametersInString);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(") {");

                        if (method.ReturnType != typeof(void))
                        {
                            jsStringBuilder.Append("var callbackId = window['" + name + "'].__newUuid();");
                        }

                        jsStringBuilder.Append("window.external.notify(JSON.stringify({");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("source: '");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(name);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("',");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("target: '");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(method.Name);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("',");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("parameters: [");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(parametersInString);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("]");

                        if (method.ReturnType != typeof(void))
                        {
                            jsStringBuilder.Append(",");
                            jsStringBuilder.Append("callbackId: callbackId");
                        }

                        jsStringBuilder.Append("}), ");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append((method.ReturnType == typeof(void)) ? (int)WebViewInteropType.InvokeMethod : (int)WebViewInteropType.InvokeMethodWithReturn);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(");");


                        if (method.ReturnType != typeof(void))
                        {
                            jsStringBuilder.Append("var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {");
                            jsStringBuilder.Append("window['" + name + "'].__callback[callbackId] = { resolve, reject };");
                            jsStringBuilder.Append("});");

                            jsStringBuilder.Append("return promise;");
                        }

                        jsStringBuilder.Append("},");
                    }
                }

                jsStringBuilder.Append("};");

                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    jsStringBuilder.Append("Object.defineProperty(");
                    jsStringBuilder.Append("window['");
                    jsStringBuilder.Append(name);
                    jsStringBuilder.Append("'], '");
                    jsStringBuilder.Append(property.Name);
                    jsStringBuilder.Append("', {");

                    if (property.CanRead)
                    {
                        webAllowedObject.FeaturesMap.TryAdd((property.Name, WebViewInteropType.GetProperty), property);

                        jsStringBuilder.Append("get: function () {");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("var callbackId = window['" + name + "'].__newUuid();");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("window.external.notify(JSON.stringify({");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("source: '");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(name);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("',");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("target: '");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(property.Name);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("',");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("callbackId: callbackId,");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("parameters: []");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("}), ");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append((int)WebViewInteropType.GetProperty);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(");");

                        jsStringBuilder.Append("var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("window['" + name + "'].__callback[callbackId] = { resolve, reject };");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("});");

                        jsStringBuilder.Append("return promise;");

                        jsStringBuilder.Append("},");
                    }

                    if (property.CanWrite)
                    {
                        webAllowedObject.FeaturesMap.TryAdd((property.Name, WebViewInteropType.SetProperty), property);

                        jsStringBuilder.Append("set: function ($$v) {");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("window.external.notify(JSON.stringify({");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("source: '");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(name);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("',");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("target: '");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(property.Name);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("',");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("parameters: [$$v]");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("}), ");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append((int)WebViewInteropType.SetProperty);
                        jsStringBuilder.Append(");");
                        jsStringBuilder.Append("},");
                    }

                    jsStringBuilder.Append("});");
                }

                jsStringBuilder.Append("})();");

                var jsString = jsStringBuilder.ToString();

                webAllowedObject.NavigationCompletedHandler = (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var isExternalObjectCustomized = webview.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "window.external.hasOwnProperty('isCustomized').toString();" }).Equals("true");

                    if (!isExternalObjectCustomized)
                    {
                        webview.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { @"
                            (function () {
                                var originalExternal = window.external;
                                var customExternal = {
                                    notify: function (message, type = 0) {
                                        if (type === 0) {
                                            originalExternal.notify(message);
                                        } else {
                                            originalExternal.notify(JSON.stringify({
                                                ___magic___: true,
                                                type: type,
                                                interop: message
                                            }));
                                        }
                                    },
                                    isCustomized: true
                                };
                                window.external = customExternal;
                            })();" });
                    }

                    webview.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { jsString });
                };

                webAllowedObject.ScriptNotifyHandler = (sender, e) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(e.Value);

                        if (message["___magic___"] != null)
                        {
                            var interopType = (WebViewInteropType)message.type;
                            var interop = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(message.interop.ToString());
                            var source = (string)interop.source.ToString();
                            var target = (string)interop.target.ToString();
                            var parameters = (object[])interop.parameters.ToObject<object[]>();

                            if (interopType == WebViewInteropType.InvokeMethod)
                            {
                                if (webAllowedObjectsMap.TryGetValue(source, out WebAllowedObject storedWebAllowedObject))
                                {
                                    if (storedWebAllowedObject.FeaturesMap.TryGetValue((target, interopType), out object methodObject))
                                    {
                                        var method = (MethodInfo)methodObject;

                                        var parameterTypes = method.GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray();

                                        var convertedParameters = new object[parameters.Length];

                                        for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
                                        {
                                            convertedParameters[i] = JsonHelper.ConvertWeaklyTypedValue(parameters[i], parameterTypes[i]);
                                        }

                                        method.Invoke(targetObject, convertedParameters);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if (interopType == WebViewInteropType.InvokeMethodWithReturn)
                            {
                                var callbackId = interop.callbackId.ToString();

                                if (webAllowedObjectsMap.TryGetValue(source, out WebAllowedObject storedWebAllowedObject))
                                {
                                    if (storedWebAllowedObject.FeaturesMap.TryGetValue((target, interopType), out object methodObject))
                                    {
                                        var method = (MethodInfo)methodObject;

                                        var parameterTypes = method.GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray();

                                        var convertedParameters = new object[parameters.Length];

                                        for (var i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
                                        {
                                            convertedParameters[i] = JsonHelper.ConvertWeaklyTypedValue(parameters[i], parameterTypes[i]);
                                        }

                                        var invokeResult = method.Invoke(targetObject, convertedParameters);

                                        webview.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { string.Format("window['{0}'].__callback['{1}'].resolve({2}); delete window['{0}'].__callback['{1}'];", source, callbackId, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invokeResult)) });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if (interopType == WebViewInteropType.GetProperty)
                            {
                                var callbackId = interop.callbackId.ToString();

                                if (webAllowedObjectsMap.TryGetValue(source, out WebAllowedObject storedWebAllowedObject))
                                {
                                    if (storedWebAllowedObject.FeaturesMap.TryGetValue((target, interopType), out object propertyObject))
                                    {
                                        var property = (PropertyInfo)propertyObject;

                                        var getResult = property.GetValue(targetObject);

                                        webview.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { string.Format("window['{0}'].__callback['{1}'].resolve({2}); delete window['{0}'].__callback['{1}'];", source, callbackId, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getResult)) });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if (interopType == WebViewInteropType.SetProperty)
                            {
                                if (webAllowedObjectsMap.TryGetValue(source, out WebAllowedObject storedWebAllowedObject))
                                {
                                    if (storedWebAllowedObject.FeaturesMap.TryGetValue((target, interopType), out object propertyObject))
                                    {
                                        var property = (PropertyInfo)propertyObject;

                                        property.SetValue(targetObject, JsonHelper.ConvertWeaklyTypedValue(parameters[0], property.PropertyType));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                };

                webview.NavigationCompleted += webAllowedObject.NavigationCompletedHandler;
                webview.ScriptNotify += webAllowedObject.ScriptNotifyHandler;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Object with the identical name is already exist.");
            }
        }

        public static void RemoveWebAllowedObject(this WebView webview, string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

            var allowedWebObjectsMap = webview.Tag as ConcurrentDictionary<string, WebAllowedObject>;

            if (allowedWebObjectsMap != null)
            {
                if (allowedWebObjectsMap.TryRemove(name, out WebAllowedObject webAllowedObject))
                {
                    webview.NavigationCompleted -= webAllowedObject.NavigationCompletedHandler;
                    webview.ScriptNotify -= webAllowedObject.ScriptNotifyHandler;

                    webview.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "delete window['" + name + "'];" });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class MyBridge
        {
            private readonly MainWindow _window;

            public MyBridge(MainWindow window)
            {
                _window = window;
            }

            public void setTitle(string title)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("SetTitle is executing...title = {0}", title));

                _window.setTitle(title);
            }

            public void playTTS(string tts)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("PlayTTS is executing...tts = {0}", tts));
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.wv.IsScriptNotifyAllowed = true;
            this.wv.ScriptNotify += Wv_ScriptNotify;
            this.wv.AddWebAllowedObject("wtjs", new MyBridge(this));

            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private void Wv_ScriptNotify(object sender, WebViewControlScriptNotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsNotification())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Value);
            }
        }

        private void setTitle(string str)
        {
            textBlock.Text = str;
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.wv.Source = new Uri("https://cmsdev.lenovo.com.cn/musichtml/leHome/weather/index.html?date=&city=&mark=0&speakerId=&reply=");
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Result

**Screenshot:**

[image: MainWindow]

---

### For Problem (3)

According to ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/layout-considerations-for-the-windowsformshost-element), [2](https://blog.qmatteoq.com/how-to-deal-with-webview-and-overlaying-elements-in-windows-8/), [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/technology-regions-overview)), it is impossible to overlay UI elements on top of `WebView`/`WebBrowser` control.

Luckily there is an alternative solution called [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) which is based on Chromium web browser and would be good enough for your use case, plus the background animation worked (which doesn't work in original `WebView` control).

However, there is no perfect solution; WPF design view is unusable with CefSharp (showing **Invalid Markup** error), but the program will just compile and run. Also, the project can only be built with either `x86` or `x64` option, `AnyCPU` will not work.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf" 
        x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="wv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="405" Margin="50,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="725" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.45,-0.75" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="335"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using CefSharp;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class MyBridge
        {
            private readonly MainWindow _window;

            public MyBridge(MainWindow window)
            {
                _window = window;
            }

            public void setTitle(string title)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("SetTitle is executing...title = {0}", title));

                _window.setTitle(title);
            }

            public void playTTS(string tts)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("PlayTTS is executing...tts = {0}", tts));
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.wv.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("wtjs", new MyBridge(this), true, new BindingOptions() { CamelCaseJavascriptNames = false });
            this.wv.FrameLoadStart += Wv_FrameLoadStart;

            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        private void Wv_FrameLoadStart(object sender, FrameLoadStartEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Url.StartsWith("https://cmsdev.lenovo.com.cn/musichtml/leHome/weather"))
            {
                e.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("CefSharp.BindObjectAsync('wtjs');");
            }
        }

        private void setTitle(string str)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                textBlock.Text = str;
            });
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.wv.Address = "https://cmsdev.lenovo.com.cn/musichtml/leHome/weather/index.html?date=&city=&mark=0&speakerId=&reply=";
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: MainWindow]

Comment: Hi DK, I met a new problem of the WebView Control. I update my main post and describe it in the last part. Could you please take a look at it and see whether you have any idea of it?

Comment: @TomXue It is impposible to overlay elements on top of `WebView`, see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help! This is what I need.